# REST APIs With Wildfly Swarm CORSFilter

Tags: java, cors, jax-rs, wildfly-10, wildfly-swarm

I have developed REST APIs With Wildfly Swarm and I would like to  introduce CORS filter and my requirement is all the header/values should be configurable in external resources .

I already implemented CORSFilter but with hard-coded header values , but now I want it configurable for Production environment .

Can anybody guide me ?

Comment: I don't think we currently have a way to set CORS headers in our project-defaults.yml config.

Could you raise an issue? https://issues.jboss.org/browse/SWARM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use properties files for exact this issue.

I have following files

- src/main/resources/cors.properties
- src/main/resources/cors.stage.properties
- src/main/resources/cors.prod.properties

than I use the maven-antrun-plugin to use the right properties file according to the selected maven profile.

```
<profile>
    <id>prod</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                            <phase>test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <tasks>
                                    <delete file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/cors.properties"/>
                                    <copy file="src/main/resources/cors.prod.properties"
                                          tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/cors.properties"/>
                                    <delete file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/cors.stage.properties"/>
                                    <delete file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/cors.prod.properties"/>
                                </tasks>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Please check https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html for the complete maven configuration.

Then you can load the properties from your resources, iterate through them and add the headers

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
InputStream in = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("cors.properties");
properties.load(in);
in.close();

for (String name : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
    addHeader(name, properties.getProperty(name));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use project-<profile>.yml to change the values depend on profile(like defaults, production, ...).

https://reference.wildfly-swarm.io/v/2017.3.2/configuration.html#_using_yaml

WRT CORSFilter, you can inject values in the yml with @ConfigurationValue.

```
import org.wildfly.swarm.spi.runtime.annotations.ConfigurationValue;

@ApplicationScoped
@Provider
public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

  @Inject @ConfigurationValue("access-control-max-age")
  private int accessControlMaxAge;

  @Override
  public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext throws IOException {
    responseContext.getHeaders().add(
      "Access-Control-Max-Age",
      accessControlMaxAge // Injected value
    );
    // other headers ...
  }
}
```

Or, you can use Undertow Filter with the yml instead of the CORSFilter.

```
swarm:
  undertow:
    filter-configuration:
      response-headers:
        access-control-max-age:
          header-name: Access-Control-Max-Age
          header-value: -1
        # other headers configuration
    servers:
      default-server:
        hosts:
          default-host:
            filter-refs:
              access-control-max-age:
                priority: 1
              # other filter refs
```

---

I've created an example has both ways.

https://github.com/emag-wildfly-swarm-sandbox/wildfly-swarm-cors-filter-demo